# Add new field to POS ticket of the restaurant module

Tags: odoo-9

I want to add a new field that contains the name of the table that had that order in the pos receip of the resaturant module, I already have searched for similar examples but couldn't solve this

I first added the variable that containes the name of the table in the models fields (this variable is in the restaurant_table class so I have done an inheritance to the restaurant_printer class) :

pos_restaurant\static\src\js\multiprint.js

```
model: 'restaurant.printer',

fields: ['name','proxy_ip','product_categories_ids','name_table'],
```

seconde I have added this line in the pos_restaurant\static\src\xml\printbill.xml

```
<div id="name_table" style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

but nothing had changed in the ticket any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

for all poeple who has interest in this I figured out how to add that field so first I thought that only the pos restaurant module files that needs to be modified so I was wrong and it's what it was all about,so the main file that should be modified is the addons\point_of_sale\static\src\xml\pos.xml ,to specifiy it's the PosTicket template,so the modification showed up right away because after all that restaurant module depends on the main point of sale

I added my code just after the shop widget like :

```
Table: <t t-esc="widget.pos.table.name"/><br />
```

and name of the table was added in the printed ticket

hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

To add fields in POS ticket you also need to add fields in 2 place
i) Need to add **models.js** file of Point of Sale. In that file there is method name "**export_for_printing**" under that method need to add your custom field. I added under "**var receipt**" name variable.

ii) After addded there to view in UI you need to add in PosTicket template located in pos.xml templates.

`<t t-name="PosTicket">`

Under this template your customized field needs to be added.